# Can I get charged with theft for taking my car if my boyfriend signs the title?

Tags: united-states, car

I am about to end my relationship and am curious to how this would work. I had my boyfriend register my car under his name because I couldn't afford it at the time.

I have definitely made up for the amount he spent on it. If he signs the title do I still have to register the car under my name or can I just leave and do it when I have a little more money to afford it?

He likes to threaten to call the cops when I take the car even though I bought it and fixed it with the money from my own pocket. He hasn't put a cent toward it since he registered it.

If I leave with the signed title can he call the cops for stealing? Even though it's my car just under his name?

---

I'm in New York I just got him to sign it. He doesn't know I'm leaving yet. I'm leaving Saturday. I am going to go down to the DMV tomorrow and see what I can do.

The only reason he signed it over is because its registered under his name and he doesn't have a license. He got pulled over the other day for it. So he signed it over after a lot of stuff. He at first refused to sign it. Because I think deep down he knows I'm leaving. But I think he thinks I'm not going to.

I'm going to see how it goes tomorrow. I just want to make sure he can't call the police and tell them I stole it.

It was my car before I met him but he likes to hold it over my head. I don't want to get arrested over his arrogance.

Comment: Looks like a case for Judge Judy! You might tell him that if he ever wants to accuse you of theft, he better make bloody sure that he is right, or he will be in deep trouble for knowingly making false accusations. The way it sounds, if you are leaving him on Saturday, that is not a second too early.

Comment: "I just want to make sure he can't call the police and tell them I stole it." Well, anyone can call the police anytime and tell them lies.

Answer (score 2):

This depends in part on where you are. Sometimes signing over the title is all it takes to transfer ownership, sometimes more is involved.

Contact your local department of motor vehicles (or equivalent)  and ask them about how to transfer ownership, about registration (probably *NOT* transferrable), about license plates (you may need new ones), and about when the next inspection will be due (here, I think they gave me a grace period of one month to complete that even though it had been inspected for the previous owner two months earlier).

Comment: Did user29093 originally do anything other than signing over the title?